# create div element with jquery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create element with `jquery` and loading html file but my code is not working I tried different ways but none of them didn't work for me first code was

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "#clickToCreateFreeAccount", function(e) {
     jQuery("</div>", {"id": "createFreeAccountDiv"}).load("js/Modals/createFreeAccount.html", function() {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery("#createFreeAccountModal").modal("show");
    });
});
```

this code was not working then I tried this one

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "#clickToCreateFreeAccount", function(e) {
     jQuery("body").append(jQuery("</div>", {"id": "createFreeAccountDiv"}).load("js/Modals/createFreeAccount.html", function() {       
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery("#createFreeAccountModal").modal("show");
    }));
});
```

This was also not working then I tried simple one to create element and third one was

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "#clickToCreateFreeAccount", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.noConflict();
     jQuery("body").append(jQuery("</div>", {id: "createFreeAccountDiv"}));
});
```

Then I saw that div element is not created I check the code and its syntax and its code is right don't know what is the problem.

Note: this code is working fine

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "#clickToCreateFreeAccount", function(e) {
    jQuery("#createFreeAccountDiv").load("js/Modals/createFreeAccount.html", function() {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery("#createFreeAccountModal").modal("show");
    });
});
```

because I already created div myself in a html file.
Now finally I don't want to create `div` myself I want to create `div` with `jquery` and load html file which has bootstrap modal.

Comment: Check the console for errors. Also note that it would be better to place the new element in the DOM *before* you attempt to `load()` content in to it

Comment: `jQuery("</div>",` need to be `jQuery("<div></div>",`

Comment: `"<div>"` instead of `"</div>"` Voted to close as TYPO

Comment: ..and google search said what?

Comment: @Satpal I tried this `jQuery("<div>", {"id": "createFreeAccountDiv"}` and it is giving error in console and error is `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).modal is not a function`

Comment: `modal is not a function` are you referencing bootstrap library? Also note you need to append div to  DOM

Comment: @Satpal yes trying to open modal if I create div myself and assign id to it and use that id and then load html file it is working fine but when I create div element with jquery and load file which has bootstrap modal.

Comment: see my updated question specially last part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery("</div>",` need to be either `jQuery("<div></div>",` Or `jQuery("<div>",`

So code need to be:-

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "#clickToCreateFreeAccount", function(e) {
     append(jQuery("<div id='createFreeAccountDiv'></div>").load("js/Modals/createFreeAccount.html", function() {       
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery("#createFreeAccountModal").modal("show");
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var config="<div>Hi Welcome</div>"
    jQuery('body').append(config);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#element_name').append('<div id"element_id_ex1" name="element_name_ex1"></div>');

or 

$("#clickToCreateFreeAccount").on('click',function()
{
    $('#element_name').append('<div id"element_id_ex1" name="element_name_ex1"></div>');
});
```